# How do I change the background color of an activity from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have `MainActivty` and `SettingsActivity`, when I press a button in my `SettingsActivity` I want the background color of the `MainActivity` to change.

How do I achieve this?
Sorry if this question is a bit dumb, I recently started out and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences. Store color in preference and on MainActivity.onCreate() read this value and set current layout background

Comment: Use a shared Preference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the color Hex as String or Integer of Color to SharedPreferences 
and get it on activity @onCreate()

```
SharedPreferences preferences= context.getSharedPreferences(
      "SharedPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("SharedPrefKey","#FF0000" /*change this to what you want*/);
editor.apply();
```

then in activity get color

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String color = preferences.getString("SharedPrefKey", "#000000");
```